# Rising Sun Lemma extension to whole real line.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was wondering whether the (1-dimensional) rising sun lemma could be extended to the whole real line. In the usual statement of the theorem, we usually assume the domain of F to be a compact interval [a,b], but I don't know whether this holds for f: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. (Say by chopping up the domain?)

Comment: @311411 Hi, thank you for the reply; yet, I do not think this post provide too much insights into whether the lemma can be extended to the whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extended rising sun lemma I found. I have proofread and revised the proof.

**lemma.** (Variant of Rising Sun Lemma)

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define
$$
   E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists y < x \text{ s.t. } g(y) < g(x)\}
   .$$
Then there exists an at most countable collection of pairwise disjoint intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ so that

$$
   E = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (a_i, b_i)
   .$$
Furthermore, for each $i$ , if $a_i > - \infty$ and $b_i < \infty$ , then

$$
   f(a_i)= f(b_i)
   .$$

**proof.**

- Since $f$ is continuous, $E$ is open. Then $E$ must be an at most countable collection of disjoint open intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ .Using continuity of $f$ , we may also verify that the intervals are separated, i.e. $a_i \neq  b_j$ for all $i, j$ .
- We only have to consider functions  $f$ where we can choose an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left(a_i, b_i\right)$ is bounded. Let us fix such an $i$ and consider $l:=\inf _{x \leq b_i-\varepsilon} f(x)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ with $a_i<b_i-\varepsilon$ .Since any $x$ with $a_i<x \leq b_i-\varepsilon$ is in $E$ , we have $l < f(x)$ on $\left(a_i, b_i-\varepsilon\right]$ .
- For $a_i - \delta < x<a_i$ , where $\delta$ is small, we have $a_i \notin E$ , so $f(x) \geq f\left(a_i\right)$ , and $f(y) \ge f(x)$ for all $y \le x$ . Thus, it follows that the infimum is attained at $a_i$ and therefore, $f\left(a_i\right) \leq f\left(b_i\right)$ . However, since $b_i \notin E$ , we also have $f\left(a_i\right) \geq f\left(b_i\right)$ .